# ActiveForm. Ошибки валидации перестали подсвечиваться красным

Tags: yii2, activeform

Всем добрый день !
Версия YII2 - 2.0.43
Заметил, что при использовании yii\widgets\ActiveForm перестали подсвечиваться красным ошибки валидации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если перехожу на использование yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm, то все ОК

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, так и должно быть или не хватает каких-то настроек ?
Спасибо.

Comment: А если вернуться на старую версию yii2 то что будет (или чуть пониже)? А то может багрепорт надо писать)

Comment: Проверьте версию `bootstrap`. Какая подключена у Вас и какая используется в `Yii2` - по-моему с версии `2.0.43` там уже `bs4` используется.